# Winodws 8/8.1 upgrade - " Display driver stopped responding and has recovered"

Tags: windows-8.1, nvidia-geforce, display-driver, windows-8.1-upgrade

### Background

Ever since I've upgraded to Windows 8 (and recently to 8.1) from Windows 7 (premium), sometimes the PC's screen gets turned off . when this happens sometimes it stays turned off, and sometimes it gets turned on and shows an error :

> "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" .

it disappears quite fast so i didn't capture it on time, but I can see many places complaining about it, even here.

Sometimes, even when I just turn on the PC, and wait for windows, the screen shuts down completely and doesn't do anything till I restart the PC (using the power button).

It's not the only driver issue I'm having with this OS. I also have a joystick that its vibration feature doesn't work anymore.

Anyway, according to what i've read over the internet, it's a common problem, can occur on multiple windows OSs and various GPU cards.

### PC information

- OS version : windows 8.1 pro 64bit
- GPU: nvidia GeForce GTS 450 GPU
- driver version: 331.58 , taken from [**here**](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/68799/en-us) .

### What I've tried

I've tried the next things, none helped me:

- upgrading the GPU driver to the latest one
- uninstalling the GPU driver and use what's Windows decides is best.
- trying out linux (ubuntu), in order to see if it's a hardware issue. it seems it works just fine there.
- writing to MS's forum. they said to talk with nvidia and that it's not their problem. I think it is related to them, since it started happening only since the day I've updated the OS. plus it's weird that nvidia made such terrible mistakes on the most popular OS...
- searching the internet and here for possible solutions. I didn't find any that really solves it. I've even tried [**this solution**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en) of MS , that is to go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers" and create a key of type "DWORD (32-bit)" and name "TdrDelay" with a value of 8.

### The question

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: You have tried installing the driver and installing it again the video driver model changed significantly in win 8.1 you did install the win 8.1 version right I have had no problems with the same card on win 8.1

Comment: Try monitoring your actually installed driver (right click in device manager) over time: first, after installing firmware driver; then after the error occurs. If you see a different driver, windows auto-"upgraded" your driver. If this is the case, disable this feature (I'm out and about and forgot where exactly; but it's also somewhere in the control panel). That said, I had this with an AW laptop under W7, and could never resolve it myself.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, i forgot to mention i've checked that the website of nvidia specifically has "windows 8.1 64 bit" as one of supported drivers. i've now updated my question to hold a link to the downloaded driver.

Comment: @gnometorule i don't understand the procedure you are offering. did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

after updating the driver, do a windows update on the driver, device manager, right click on the vga card properties, and update driver.. fixed it for me

Comment: after updating the driver, the windows update doesn't allow to update any further.